# How to select active Word document from Access VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-word

I wrote some VBA in Access which to export data to one Excel sheet and two Word docs. If I have no other Word docs open everything works. If another instance of Word is running, some of my selections and data ends up in this other open Word document.

The error occurs at the `Selection.EndKey....` point. I know that it is because I am referencing that selection in Word from Access.

How do I reference that selection, so it does it in the "wDoct" document?

The selection takes the last line and makes it bold, then moves one tab to the right and inserts more data.

```vb
Public Sub ExportToWord()

Dim wApp As Word.Application
Dim wDoc As Word.Document
Dim wDoct As Word.Document
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim exApp As Excel.Application
Dim exWb As Excel.Workbook
Dim exWs As Excel.Worksheet
Dim nextrow As Long
Dim rng As Word.Range

Set wApp = New Word.Application
Set wDoc = wApp.Documents.Open("C:\Users\Peter\Documents\testdoc.docm", ReadOnly:=False)
Set wDoct = wApp.Documents.Open("C:\Users\Peter\Documents\Trends.docx")
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Overall")
Set exApp = New Excel.Application
Set exWb = exApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Peter\Documents\727TRACKER.xlsx", ReadOnly:=False)
Set exWs = exWb.Worksheets("MIS")

If Not rs.EOF Then rs.MoveLast

wDoc.Bookmarks("name").Range.Text = Nz(rs!Name, "")

nextrow = exWs.Cells(exWs.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1 'select last row in tracker
exWs.Range("A" & nextrow).Value = Nz(rs!Name, "")  'insert to last row

wDoct.Content.InsertAfter Text:=vbCr & Nz(rs!Name, "") & "date" 'insert last row in Word
Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdStory  'this is where it fails (select last row in and make bold)
Selection.MoveStart Unit:=wdLine, Count:=-1
Set rng = Selection.Range

With rng.Font
    .Bold = True
End With

Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
Selection.TypeText Text:=vbTab
Selection.Font.Bold = wdToggle
Selection.TypeText Text:=Nz(rs!Name, "")

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Grades")

If Not rs.EOF Then rs.MoveLast

wDoc.Bookmarks("briefQ").Range.Text = Nz(rs!PlanQ, "")
wDoc.Bookmarks("briefQmin").Range.Text = Nz(rs!PlanQMin, "")

With wDoc.Content.Find
    .Text = "True"
    .Replacement.Text = "X"
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End With

With wDoc.Content.Find
    .Text = "False"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End With

Dim ctlList As Control, strItems As String, index As Integer

Set ctlList = Forms!Grades1!List96

For index = 0 To ctlList.ListCount - 1
    If ctlList.Selected(index) Then
        strItems = strItems & ctlList.Column(0, _
          index) & ";"
    End If
Next index
 
wDoc.Bookmarks("type").Range.Text = strItems

wApp.DisplayAlerts = False
wDoc.SaveAs2 "C:\Users\Peter\Documents\" & rs!ID & "_gradesheet.docm"
wDoc.Close
wDoct.Save
wApp.Quit

exApp.DisplayAlerts = False
exWb.Close True

Set exWs = Nothing
Set exWb = Nothing
exApp.Quit
Set exApp = Nothing

Set wApp = Nothing
Set wDoc = Nothing
Set wDoct = Nothing
Set rng = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using this instead:

```
wDoct.Content.InsertAfter Text:=vbCr & Nz(rs!name, "") & "date" 'insert last row in          Word
wDoct.Content.InsertAfter Text:=vbTab & "name"
wDoct.Range(Start:=wDoct.Paragraphs.Last.Range.Start,     End:=wDoct.Paragraphs.Last.Range.Start + 10).Bold = True
```